# ¿Cómo determinar el menor de un conjunto de números ingresados por pantalla siendo el máximo a ingresar 10?

Tags: c++

Necesito ayuda con mi codigo ya que cumple la funcion de acumular los valores pero a la hora de indicarme cual es el menor de todos los ingresados solo me indica el ultimo ingresado por pantalla y no el menor del conjunto. Adjunto codigo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    signed int v = 0, a = 0, b = 0, menor, menor2;

    cout << "ingrese valores negativos y positivos, luego pulse 0 para finalizar" << endl;

    int i = 1;

        do {
        cin >> v;

        if (v < 0) {
            a = a + 1;
        } else {
            a = a;
        }

        if (v < 10 || v < 0) {
            b = b + 1;
        } else {
            b = b;
        }

        if (a == 10 && a / 10 == 1) {
            cout << "se ingresaron 10 valores negativos" << endl;

            if (i) {
                menor = v;
            }

            if (v < menor) {
                menor = v;
            }
            cout << "El menor es " << menor << endl;
            v = 0;
            a = 0;
            b = 0;
        }

        if (b == 10 && b / 10 == 1) {
            cout << "Se ingresaron 10 valores negativos y/o positivos" << endl;

            if (i) {
                menor2 = v;
            }

            if (v < menor2) {
                menor2 = v;
            }
            cout << "El menor es " << menor2 << endl;
            v = 0;
            a = 0;
            b = 0;
        }

        i++;
    } while (i < a || i > a || v != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: El máximo a ingresar se refiere a la cantidad de número leidos o al valor máximo del cada número leído?

Comment: El maximo a ingresar se refiere a la cantidad maxima que el acumulador permite. Es el que dice a.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te refieres a esto:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int v = 0, a = 0, b = 0, menor;
    //asumiendo que, a: almacena conteo de valores negativos y b: almacena conteo de valores positivos
    cout << "ingrese valores negativos y positivos, luego pulse 0 para finalizar" << endl;

    int i = 1;

    do {
        cout <<"Número "<< i << " = ";
        cin >> v;

        if (v < 0) //valor negativo
            a++;
        if( v > 0) //en caso que el valor sea positivo
            b++;
        
        if(i==1) //asignar el primer número como el menor, cuando i = 1
            menor = v;
        if(v < menor)  //reasignar el menor
            menor = v;
        i++;
    } while (v != 0);

    cout<<"Se ingresaron "<< a << " números negativos"<<endl;
    cout<<"Se ingresaron "<< b << " números positivos"<<endl;
    cout<<"Se ingresaron "<< a + b << " números en total"<<endl;
    cout<<"El menor de todos es: " << menor<< endl;

    return 0;
}
```

La variable menor2, no se para que propósito la utilizarías.

Comment: Si! Es algo similar a lo que hiciste ahi solo que lo que yo hice es que el programa itere y no pare hasta que ingrese un 0. La var menor2 la use para que almacene negativos y positivos menores que 10 porque unifique todo un ejercicio en este

Comment: Hay forma de que te contacte y te pase la consigna?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta, y pon toda la especificación. Estaré atento.

Comment: Si cambias   =>  } while (v != 0);
queda esperando a que digites 0 para terminar de leer valores
Esta condición también puedes modificarla para que no valide que sea menor o igual que 10:
 if( v > 0) //en caso que el valor  positivo